# Memory card formatting needed

Tags: sd-card, formatting

I am using Micromax P470 tablet. My memory card was fine but suddenly it appeared that I need to format my memory card. I removed my memory card and connected to a PC. It was opening and I could see all my files. But if I put it on my tablet then it is showing "need formatting". I tried to format on phone. It is still the same. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I would connect your memory card to your computer and back up everything you can, then on your tablet, let Android format your memory card. Once Android formats your memory card, put it back in your PC and move everything from the backup to the memory card. Then just put it back in your tablet to see if it works.

If that does not work, you could try reformatting it on your computer. In Windows, just go to "Computer", then right your memory card and click format. On the window that comes up, everything should be set already, so just click start.

Note: Using Android or Windows to format your memory card will erase everything... That's why I told you to back up everything on your card.

If formatting it on Android and Windows does not work, then it is possible your memory card has died and you need a new one.